# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'XXX-XXX' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

#### Preconditions

1. Migrating from Magento 1.9.3.10
2. Migrating to Magento 2.3.5-p1 using Data Migration Tool

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Run Settings migration as usual
2. Run Data migration as usual

#### Expected result

1. Migration with no errors or integrity step failing with details

#### Actual result

1. `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'XX-XXX' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'`

#### Additional notes

I have 44 attribute sets in my M1 database. This error only comes up with 2 of those (Attribute set IDs 9 and 12).

I've already checked my M1 & M2 databases and there are no duplicated entries as the error says. Also, this was recognized as a bug on a previous version of [Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/201).

The suggested solution was comment/remove remove a method at `Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php` and add the attributes manually to the sets.

**Is there a official / tested fix for this or somebody knows what it means?** (Again, there are no duplicated entries)

**Note:** Here is a list with some of the `attribute_set_id` / `attribute_id` combination which fails.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9-110' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9-503' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9-863' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '12-111' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'
```

(The same happen to almost all attributes assigned to attribute sets 9 and 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of Data Migration Tool `2.3.5`.

It worked using the same M1 database, but downgrading my M2 to version `2.3.4`.

Comparing the `2.3.4` and `2.3.5` results, I found that the file `Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php` was completely rewritten and the renaming step from `Default` to `Migration_Default` for the Attribute Set contained in `eav_attribute_set` table were removed on the latest version of Data Migration Tool.

In this scenario, there is a very high probability to get constrains like this: `Duplicate entry 'xxx-xxx' for key 'EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'.`

Here is a patch for DMT 2.3.5 to fix this issue: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/commit/46c1d11d598daba30681f700c63718740c77ba15

Answer (score 0):

You need to make empty all below tables: **eav_attribute_set**, **eav_entity_attribute**, **eav_attribute_group** and run the migration process again.

Comment: Did it. Doesn't work.

Comment: not working. any other solution?